# Weird error with Facebook Messenger Platform/bot Welcome Confugration

Tags: facebook, bots, messenger, facebook-messenger

I'm getting a weird error while configuring welcome message for my Messenger bot. I've been using the same code (as shown below) and it has just been working fine until last night. I tried it with both cURL and [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). Neither of them works.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
  "thread_state":"new_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "message":{
        "text":"Welcome to My Company!"
      }
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<PAGE_ID>/thread_settings?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

**Error message when executing the code above:**

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Invalid keys \"message\" were found in param \"call_to_actions[0]\".","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"Hn42Wa+hapI"}}%
```

I can confirm both PAGE_ID and PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN are correct as trying to delete the welcome message with the following code works fine.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
  "thread_state":"new_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "message":{
        "text":"Welcome to My Company!"
      }
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<PAGE_ID>/thread_settings?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

Also, the code I'm using is exactly the same as shown on the [Facebook official API doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#welcome_message_configuration). I don't understand why it's saying "message" is not a valid key. Is anyone experiencing the same problem? Did Facebook change their api?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Been trying to solve this for hours. Glad to see people having the same problem, in a way that we can confirm this error is not caused by us. Maybe an undocumented API change?

Comment: @ericls I would reckon it's an undocumented API change. Hope further notification will be given soon.

Comment: Bug has been reported here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1751749508372552/

Answer (score 7):

The [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#welcome_message_configuration) are now updated, you need to define your payload in  `payload` parameter now (a UTF-8 encoded string), eg:

```
"call_to_actions":[
    {
      "payload":"USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
    }
]
```

Comment: The updated doc doesn't work either. I got the following error:

`{"error":{"message":"(#3) App must be on whitelist","type":"OAuthException","code":3,"fbtrace_id":"FiDgnEghdY\/"}}`

Comment: The same for me - the "thread_settings" endpoint worked fine just 2 days ago. Now after using "payload" I am getting the whitelist error.

Comment: te@leihe, you sure your app isnt in sandbox (testing) mode?

Answer (score 1):

Docs updated:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/greeting-text

Example:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type":"greeting",
  "greeting":{
    "text":"Welcome to My Company!"
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the same issue and fix it.
I think your json of request is

```
let messageData = {
"setting_type":"call_to_actions",
"thread_state":"new_thread",
"call_to_actions":[
  {
    "payload":"welcome_payload"
  }
]
}
request({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings',
    qs: {access_token:token},
    method: 'POST',
    json: {
        messageData
    }
}
```

but it will not work and log will say you have no "setting_type" = =a 
try this one

```
  request({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings',
        qs: {access_token:token},
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            setting_type:"call_to_actions",
            thread_state:"new_thread",
             call_to_actions:[
              {
                "payload":"welcome_payload"
              }
             ]
        }
    }
```

it work for me.

Answer (score -1):

This error was due to an API change.

New call:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
  "thread_state":"new_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[{
    "payload":"START"
  }]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<PAGE_ID>/thread_settings?access_token=<PAGE_TOKEN>"
```

Just add a payload like `{"payload":"START"}`

If a user press the "Getting started" button, you receive this payload in your messageHandler (webhook). Check if `$incomingMessage == "START"` and send back your structured message, or whatever you want.

Messages like before are not supported anymore.

Bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1751749508372552/