# Facebook Messenger API Error: Payload cannot be empty for postback type button

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I successfully set up Greeting Text, and now I trying to set up a payload for a Get Started button by this [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/get-started-button):

I send exactly:

```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type":"call_to_actions",
  "thread_state":"new_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "payload":"START"
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

but receive an error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Payload cannot be empty for postback type button","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"GWv5XughbUQ"}}
```

What i do wrong?

Comment: Documentation says `call_to_actions` must be an array of payload strings, but [{}] is an array containing an object. Try with just a simple array. (And if that works, you might as well be so kind to file a documentation bug, so that they can get the example fixed. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs)

Comment: `"call_to_actions":[  "START" ]` cause the same error.

Comment: Seems to me as if you're doing it right. I'd generate a new page access token and make sure that's not the issue, though, I doubt that's the problem. I'd guess there's some mismatch between what is posted in this question and what code you're actually running.

Comment: I guess it's a bug because there was a similar [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105320/weird-error-with-facebook-messenger-platform-bot-welcome-confugration)
And it won't work with updated access token.

Comment: I tried your exact curl request with my own chatbot, it works. You probably have stumbled upon some kind of bug, report that to the facebook to get it fixed. Messenger platform is still in the beta stage, things like that are to be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found my mistake. [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743645/facebook-messenger-api-error-payload-cannot-be-empty-for-postback-type-button/38787125#comment64862493_38743645) said I was wrong in request structure.

I used PHP and sent:

```
$requset = [
    'call_to_actions' =>  [
       'payload' =>  'START'
    ],
    'setting_type' => 'call_to_actions',
    'thread_state' => 'new_thread'
];
```

But right form is:

```
$requset = [
        'call_to_actions' =>  [
           ['payload' =>  'START']
        ],
        'setting_type' => 'call_to_actions',
        'thread_state' => 'new_thread'
    ];
```